# Apache windows uninstall path?

Tags: apache-2.2, windows, uninstall, silent

I'm trying to find the path of the uninstall file for Apache 2.2. I can see it in Add/Remove Programs, and tried to find the uninstall path in the registry under `HKLM\software\microsoft\windows\currentversion\uninstall` but there is no folder for Apache....

I'm trying to find the path because I'm making an install file which installs Apache/PHP/MySQL` and want to uninstall any existing installations of those 3 beforehand.

I know that running the Apache installer gives you the option of Repair/Remove if it's already installed but I want the uninstall to be silent/automated, so that the end user doesn't have to manually select remove to actually uninstall the existing apache.

Answer (score 0):

[Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) can help you. While you uninstall from Control Panel, it shows real time the file system, Registry, and process activity.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know how I can use it for this case? It seems pretty overwhelming and it looks like I need to filter the events.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/317877/using-process-monitor-to-track-registry-changes